# Raku - String invoking anonymous regex

Tags: raku

Why does the first expression interpret but not the second?
I understand them to be identical, that is, a string invoking an anonymous regex.

```
("foo").first: /foo/ andthen say "$_ bar";
> foo bar
```

```
"foo": /foo/ andthen say "$_ bar";
> Confused
> at /home/dmc7z/raku/foo.raku:2
> ------> "foo":⏏ /foo/ andthen say "$_ bar";
>     expecting any of:
>         colon pair
```

Comment: I’m guessing, but from the documentation of  the`first` routine (under List), it appears it’s a function that takes a lost and a reflex and returns the first match, ie it’s a function with the concept of *matching* built in, taking (effectively) two parameters. Your second example, the one that’s failing, has no function or operator which applies a match. Maybe you want `~~` or something (though this won’t do the same thing, ie trim results down to the first match).

Comment: Raku's `first` command seems very similar to Raku's `grep`. Do you see similar issues/problems in syntax?

Comment: @jubilatious1j `.first(...)` is the same as `.grep(...).head`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a method call:

```
 ("foo").first: /foo/
```

It's the same as if you had written:

```
("foo").first( /foo/ )
```

Or just:

```
"foo".first( /foo/ )
```

(Note that I used `:` at the end of the three above descriptions in English. That's where the idea to use `:` to mean that whatever following it is part of the same expression comes from.)

In this case it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to use `first`. Instead I would use `~~`.

```
"foo" ~~ /foo/ andthen say "$_ bar";
```

---

`first` is used to find the first item in a list that matches some description. If you use it on a single item it will either return the item, or return `Nil`. It always returns one value, and `Nil` is the most sensible single undefined value in this case.

---

The reason it says it's expecting a colon pair is that is the only use of `:` that could be valid in that location. Honestly I halfway expected it to complain that it was an invalid label.

Comment: Thank you. Your clarification that it's just a method call is what I needed.